# How to Determine Type of Login that User Used in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth, authorization, meteor-accounts

I am looking for the best way to determine type of service that user used to login into the system. I mean something like Meteor.user().typeOfLogin() that will return e.g('facebook', 'google', 'password')... or at least maybe someone know the reliable way how to manually check it.

I looked at official docs but I didn't find anything useful: http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `underscore` added in your project.

```
Meteor.users.helpers({
    typeOfLogin: function() {
            if (_.has(this.services, 'facebook'))
                return 'facebook';
            if (_.has(this.services, 'google'))
                 return 'google';
        }
});
```

Comment: That would tell you if they have a service, but not if they just used it to login if they have more than one.

Comment: absolutely right. I didn't think about this use when answering this question. thanks for your valuable feedback.